# How to configure a catch-all CNAME on Ubuntu Linux using BIND 9

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I'm trying to set up APE server on my local system.  I'm using Ubuntu and BIND and I need to set up a catch-all `CNAME` record.

What would be required for this?

Answer (score 5):

Set up a zone for your domain in `named.conf.local` and create the zone file with the basics, if you haven't already.

In the zone file, you want something like this:

```
*  IN  CNAME  whereever.it.needs.to.point.com.
```

Comment: And you need the `A` resource-record for the `CNAME` to point at.